# grok learning: python course, printing backwards

Tags: python

One of the questions on the grok learning python course is, "Write a program that reads in a line of text and prints out the line of text backwards."I wrote:

```
word = input('Line: ')
for i in range(len(word)):
  i = (0 - 1 - i)
  print(word[i],end = "")
```

This gives any entered text back to the user backwards but when I submit it it says "Your output is missing a trailing newline character." Does this mean that the answer is incorrect because any new print statements will print text on the same line as the entered word?

Comment: I copy pasted your code and it worked.

Comment: Put a new line at the end of your print statement. It might be looking for an empty line at the end of your script

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is store the reverse of the word in another variable `new_word` and then print that after the for loop.

```
word = input('Line: ')
new_word = ""

for i in range(len(word)):
    i = (0 - 1 - i)
    new_word += word[i]

  print(new_word)
```

Comment: For a toy problem like this one, it doesn't really matter much how you do it, but this method is not a great choice. Every time you `+=` the next letter, you create a new string since strings are immutable, increasing runtime and memory usage. The usual idiom for doing string creation is to create a list of the characters/substrings and doing `''.join()` on the list at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory one-liner:

```
>>> "This is my string in reverse"[::-1]
'esrever ni gnirts ym si sihT'
```

Including an input prompt:

```
>>> input('Line: ')[::-1]
Line: this is my stuff
'ffuts ym si siht'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to make Python speak backwards, and all of them work, and I hope they help you.

Here are some solutions that Grok Learning itself recommends:

- Sample solution #1:

```
text = input('Line: ')
last_index = len(text) - 1
backwards_text = ''
for i in range(last_index, -1, -1):
    backwards_text = backwards_text + text[i]
print(backwards_text)
```

- Sample solution #2:

```
line = input('Line: ')
for i in range(len(line)-1, -1, -1):
  print(line[i], end='')
print()
```

These both work, and they both use a slight different way on how to print backwards, but they both use a `for` loop, and I hope both of these help you, and I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score -1):

```
y = input("Line: ")

print(y[::-1])
```

works like a beauty
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­